# Xamarin.Android: Problems changing the application icon from the default icon

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I just started learning how to develop for Android a few days ago, so I'm still in the process of learning all the ins and out of the environment. Recently, I finished writing the functionality for a basic Contacts app and decided to turn to fixing some of the finer points of the UI. I have been trying for the last couple of days to change the launcher icon for the app from the default Android icon [Default Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8sM6.png) to one that I selected [Selected Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VckzF.png). However, nothing I seem to try will allow the icon I selected to appear on the device I am testing on.

I added what is supposed to be the proper line in the Android Manifest file as seen here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"package="Contact_Manager.Contact_Manager" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="internalOnly">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<application android:label="Contacts" android:icon ="@drawable/contacts-3"></application></manifest>
```

But this solution did not work. I also tried deleting the default icon from the drawable folder(I also saved a copy of it elsewhere) but it still showed the default Icon on the device screen. I then tried to uninstall the application on the device in order to clear all the cache files, but was met with the same outcome. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Note: I am also new to StackOverFlow so I apologize if the formatting of this question is awful.

Comment: "_But this solution did not work_" why?

Comment: It still displayed the default icon even after changing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have not deleted all the versions of default icon. In android there is a icon for each screen density in drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, etc folder. Hence search for that file and remove it from all the folders and try again.

You need to add fresh icons for each density.

```
UPDATE 1 :
```

I think I know the problem now. Right click the project on solution explorer. Then click on options. Then Build-Android Application.

Change the application icon there.

Comment: There are no other instances of the file Icon.png(name of the default image) anywhere in the project folder. I would think at the very least it would throw some kind of error upon not finding the file, but that image is the one that continues to be used

Comment: Try a clean build then, I don't see anything which you are doing wrong.

Comment: I seemed to get further in doing a clean build, however now it is telling me that I'm making a reference to the old icon in line 12 of my manifest file. I looked at the manifest file and there is no reference to the old icon, in fact the file only goes to line 6.

Comment: By any chance do you have two AndroidManifest file in your project.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I actually have three. two of them are identical and do have the problematic reference but one of them does not. Coincidentally, the one without the reference is the only one I can observe and change in Visual Studio

Comment: Try changing the other two from outside the project then.

Comment: I keep changing it, but every time i deploy the project it changes it back

Comment: By any chance in the class which is extending Application is the android:icon property set. For eg :  [Application(Enabled = true, LargeHeap = true)]

Comment: So now the icon for the application is all set, but it is throwing me an error because the icon it set for the Main Activity no longer exists. Every time I try to change the name of the activity icon to the name of my icon, Visual Studio comes up with a dialog box telling me about unsaved changes and asking me if I want to reload the files. If I say yes, it reverts the change I just made and if I say no, it keeps the file but also keeps throwing the error

Comment: Try cleaning the code. If still it doesn't work. Add those icons again. Then change the icon to some other icon. Finally delete the old icons. Very strange issues in Xamarin ! :(

Answer (score 3):

Try with a different icon name

Copy the new icon(myIcon.png) into mipmap- folders.

[image]

Update the icon value in Android project MainActivity.cs file

[image]

**Uninstall** the application from your device and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the default `icon.png` files from all the Android drawable folders, and save your new icon as `icon.png`. Also make sure that in the manifest you point to the icon file:

`<application android:label="<Your app name>" android:icon="@drawable/icon"></application>`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Deleted the old icons (maybe you only removed them from project not deleted them? I dont know) and tried building. It threw errors wherever the old icon was referenced so I was able to trace the issue. Also removing the old and adding the new with the same name (Icon.png) worked for me